# How can I get the results of multiplying 2 doubles, and allow up to 1% error?

Tags: java, math, double

Lets say I have program that will generate 2 random doubles, and then asks the user what is the answer.

An example would be the code below, given that num1 and num2 is randomly generated, and userAnswer is the answer that the user has keyed in.

```
if(num1 * num2 == userAnswer)
{
    System.out.Println("You are right!");
}
```

I understand that multiplying doubles would never be accurate, but how can I change this code to allow errors up to 3 decimal points? I want the console to still display "You are right", even though the answer is 2.1453000001 and the user answers 2.145.

Comment: simply round it to 3 decimal points?

Comment: Your question title says 1% error, but then you say you want 3 decimal points precision. Those are not the same (and you've got answers for both options).

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to check for up to one percent error you could use

```
quotient = userAnswer / (num1 * num2);
if (quotient > 0.99 && quotient < 1.01) {
```

This of course assumes that the correct answer is not `0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Eg:

```
double d=2.1453000001;
double formatted= Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("#.###").format(d));
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Output:

```
2.145
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
public static String format(String format,Object... args)
```

> **if you don’t want to print out the String and just want to format it for later use**, you can use the static format method of the String
>   class (sort of like sprintf in C). It works in exactly the same way as
>   printf as far as formatting is concerned, but it doesn’t print the
>   String, it returns a new formatted String.

**Floating point formatting**

`%f`      : will print the number as it is.

`%15f`    : will pint the number as it is. If the number has less than 15 digits, the output will be padded on the left.

`%.8f` : will print maximum 8 decimal digits of the number.

`%9.4f` : will print maximum 4 decimal digits of the number. The output will occupy 9 characters at least. If the number of digits is not enough, it will be padded

**For Example**:

```
    double d=12.23429837482;
    String s = String.format("%.3f", d);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
12.234
```

Comment: I think you and I have understood the question differently.  I thought the OP wanted to know how to tell if a `double` supplied by the user was within 1% of a `double` that somehow came from within the program.  So the means of comparison was the whole point of the question.  You're not doing any sort of comparison at all.  But I might have understood the question completely incorrectly; so I haven't applied any sort of vote to this answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace To me, everybody posts variety of flavors. Thank you for checking my post :)

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't help that OP has asked two quite different questions - one in the title of the post, and one in the body.  I'm tempted to VTC it as unclear.

Comment: I did cuz you are right